# android check box star style

Tags: android, android-widget

I am new to android development but I know how to create a starStyled checkbox using xml as

```
<CheckBox style="?android:attr/starStyle">
```

But how to set starStyle using code i.e, by creating check box like this

```
CheckBox cb=new CheckBox(this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of  using the constructor **CheckBox cb=new CheckBox(this);** ,why don't you use **CheckBox cb=new CheckBox(this,null,android.R.attr.starStyle);**